# ¿ Como hacer comienzo de una web igual en dispositivos móviles que en el ordenador?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive, navbar

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con la barra de navegación de un sitio web en dispositivos móviles.
En pantalla grande, en el ordenador, a entrar en el sitio se ve una imagen, y los link de la barra de navegación, pero esta barra no se ve hasta que no hacemos scrool, cuando aparece de color blanca.
Mi intención seria que en los dispositivos móviles fuese de la misma forma, ya que  ahora, como muestro en la captura, al entrar en el sitio se vería la barra de navegación desde el principio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿ Seria posible que en dispositivos móviles al entrar en el sitio lo primero que se viera fuera la imagen como en el PC ?
Solo muestro el css que he creído conveniente pues es muy extenso. Espero con esto puedan darme alguna idea de como modificar para conseguir mi propósito.

Así se vería en el PC:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias.

```css
.finance-navbar.affix {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed !important;
    margin: 0;
    animation: fadeItIn 1s;
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.finance-navbar.affix .logo {
    margin: 14px 0;
    width: 229px;
}
.finance-navbar.affix .nav > li {
    padding: 21px 0!important;
}
.finance-navbar.affix a.request_quote {
    display: none;
}
@keyframes fadeItIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        -moz-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}
.hdr_variation2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.navbar-default {
    background: none;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.navbar-default:after {
    display: none;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar .nav > li a.nav_drop_ar:after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(../images/common_in_all/nav2_dropar.png) no-repeat scroll center bottom;
}

.nav_variation4_in {
    border: 1px solid #aac263;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-collapse.nav_variation4 {
    background: #85a820;
    padding: 4px;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-collapse.nav_variation4 .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-collapse.nav_variation4 .nav > li {
    padding: 10px 0px!important;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-collapse.nav_variation4 .nav > li a {
    color: #fff;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-collapse.nav_variation4.nav_variation5 .navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #131313;
    padding: 8px 115px 8px 0;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-collapse.nav_variation4.nav_variation5 .navbar-nav::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 64px solid #131313;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 0px;
}
a.var4_request_btn {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 194px;
    background: #799d1c;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
a.var4_request_btn:hover {
    background: #000;
}
a.var5_request_btn {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #131313;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 64px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    width: 235px;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.variation4_navbar.navbar-default {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.variation4_navbar .dropdown-submenu > li > a {
    color: #000;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.variation4_navbar .dropdown-submenu > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.finance-navbar.affix#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.variation4_navbar.navbar-default {
    background: #85a820;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.variation4_navbar.variation5_navbar,
#main-navigation-wrapper.finance-navbar.affix.variation2_navbar.variation4_navbar.variation5_navbar.navbar-default {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: rgba(166, 198, 68, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 50%, rgba(166, 198, 68, 1) 50%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 50%, rgba(166, 198, 68, 1) 50%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 50%, rgba(166, 198, 68, 1) 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 50%, rgba(166, 198, 68, 1) 50%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 50%, rgba(166, 198, 68, 1) 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 50%, rgba(166, 198, 68, 1) 50%);
}
#main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-collapse.nav_variation5 {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
}

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background: #33381e;
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar {
        background: #557c2a;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
        height: 0!important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: auto!important;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
        background: #e6e8df;
        padding: 0px 0px !important;
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
        height: auto !important;
        max-height: 70vh;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .header #main-navigation .nav {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav .dopdown-nav-toggler {
        width: 49px;
        height: 49px;
        float: right;
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
        margin: -15px 0 0 0;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav .dopdown-nav-toggler:before {
        position: absolute;
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        border: none;
        content: "\f078";
        top: 15px;
        color: #474747;
        right: 27px;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav .dopdown-nav-toggler.dopdown-nav-toggler-active:before {
        position: absolute;
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        border: none;
        content: "\f077";
        top: 15px;
        color: #474747;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav .dopdown-nav-toggler .icon-bar {
        /*background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1px;
        display: block;
        height: 1px;
        width: 20px;*/
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav .dopdown-nav-toggler .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li > a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 10px 15px 30px;
        background: url(../images/common_in_all/nav_list_bg.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
        position: relative;
        color: #474747;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    #main-navigation-wrapper.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
    #main-navigation-wrapper.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    #main-navigation-wrapper.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
        background: url(../images/common_in_all/nav_list_bg.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-submenu a {
        background: url(../images/common_in_all/nav_dropdownlist_bg.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-submenu a:hover {
        color: #9acc41;
        background: url(../images/common_in_all/nav_dropdownlist_bg.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li.dropdown.dropdown-active > a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #12121b;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li:last-child > a {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li + li > a {
        border-left: none;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        left: auto;
        right: auto;
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        transition: none !important;
        display: none;
        top: auto;
        float: none;
        background: #33381e;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-submenu a {
        color: #9acc41;
    }
    .finance-navbar.affix a.request_quote {
        display: block;
    }
    .affix .logo-menu {
        margin: 12px 0 13px 18px;
    }
    .affix .navbar-toggle {
        margin: 12px 15px 13px 0;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .navbar-nav ul.dropdown-submenu li.new {
        display: none;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li > a {
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li + li > a {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper .nav > li a.nav_drop_ar:after {
        display: none;
    }
    #main-navigation-wrapper.variation2_navbar.navbar-default {
        /*background: #000;*/
        background: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle.variation2_navbar .icon-bar {
        /*background: #fff;*/
        background: #9acc41;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MI</title> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Header Topbar Start-->
  <div class="hdr_variation2">
    <div class="hdr_col">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="hdr_top_bar hdr_top_bar_var3">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 mobile_none"><span class="landing_gardening_txt">Bienvenido a Nuestra Web...</span></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 hdr_cnt">
              <ul>
                <li class="hdr_call_icon var3_white white_call_icon">677 33 26 31</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="main-navigation-wrapper" class="variation2_navbar navbar navbar-default finance-navbar">
      <div class="thm-container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="logo-menu"><img src="images/common_in_all/logoNuevo.png" alt="logo"></div>
          <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle variation2_navbar collapsed"><span
              class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
              class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div id="main-navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><a href="index.html" class="logo fl"><img src="images/common_in_all/logoNuevo.png"
              alt="logo"></a><a href="index.html" class="logo-sticky fl"><img src="images/home_page2/index2_logo.png"
              alt="logo"></a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav small_hgt">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav_drop_ar">Servicios</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav_drop_ar">Galeria</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="minimal-bootstrap-carousel" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade shop-slider">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides-->
    <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner ver_new_3_slider">
      <div class="item active slide-1">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="thm-container">
            <div class="box valign-top home1_slide1">
              <div class="content text-left wdt55 cnt_fl">
                <h2 data-animation="animated fadeInUp">LA EXPERIENCIA</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wdt_100 pad_85_100">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="year_quality"><span class="year_35">25</span> Años de Experiencia
        y Servicio <span class="landscanp_color">Desbrozando</span>
      </div>
        <p>Realizamos todo tipo de desbroces y limpiezas en fincas, terrenos y parcelas </p>
      <div class="quality-list">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 quality-list_marbtm"><a href="planting_removal.html" class="image_hover mbot_38"><img
                src="" alt="image" class="zoom_img_effect"></a>  </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pad_100_97 why_choose_col wdt_100"></div>
  <div class="pad_94_100 client_bg wdt_100"></div>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías hacer que el color del fondo de la nav-bar para dispositivos móviles en vez de blanco fuese **transparent** modificando el CSS oportuno.

Comment: Si usas Bootstrap, revisa los `media querys`. Debes tener en las vistas más pequeñas (>768px), alguna propiedad en tu `nav-bar` que tenga ese color blanco; como te dice @PHPMyguel cambia ese valor por `transparent`.

Comment: Ok, estoy tratando de ver cual corresponde a esa parte, pues en varios sitios, esta como trasparente: `.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
        margin: 15px 15px 15px 0;
        border-color: #fff;
        background-color: transparent !important;
        border: none;
    }`  A ver si encuentro el adecuado. Claro que debería editar todos los media querys, para que funcione en todos .Pero no se cual es exactamente la clase que debo cambiar. ¿ Cual seria del html ?

Comment: Sólo busca en tus hojas de estilo las clases relacionadas con tu `nav-bar` que tengan la propiedad `background-color: #fff;` (o _white_). Otra cosa que puede suceder, es que tu proyecto tenga scripts que dependiendo de una resolución dada, aplique ciertas propiedades CSS a tu sitio.

Comment: Usa el **inspeccionar** del navegador, es tu amigo y te dirá las clases que están afectando al elemento. Si juegas un ratito con él descubrirás cual es el selector CSS que está afectando al fondo, incluso te dirá la linea y el archivo donde se encuentra para poder modificarlo cómodamente.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo. Ahora tratare de estudiar la forma del inspector del navegador. O buscare las clases que puedan afectar a la barra de navegación. Ya les comentare como me fue